# Node.js: global variable creation

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use Nodejs to make SQL queries, and I'd like to save the result  in a global variable, in order to use it in the rest of the file, I tried to use express and the global.storage, but no result yet, the console shows me undefined, my code is so below : and the result that is shown in the console is null.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "espace_membre"
});

var pseudo1 = "amine";
var socketid = '3485858585';
var peerId = '4444';
var sqlResult = null ; // stockera une sortie SQL

con.connect(function(err) {
  con.query("SELECT gender FROM gender WHERE socketid = '" + peerId + "'", function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    // affect la sortie à la variable global
    sqlResult = result;
  });
});

console.log( sqlResult );
```

Comment: Here is a very detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/12749132

Comment: `console.log(result);` should indeed log the query result. Also, this question is not *at all* about variable creation.

Comment: thanks for the link, i used it and it helped me.